# What is the correct address for an image in a markdown document in VSTS?

Tags: git, markdown, azure-devops, visual-studio-code

I have a README.md file in the root of my git repository hosted in Visual Studio Team Services.

When I navigate to the file in the web browser through the project portal I can see the correctly rendered markdown except for the images. I would like to add some screenshots to the README file and would like to know the correct way to reference an image stored stored in a folder at the `root of the repository/doc/images/image01.png`

As the README file is also stored at the root of the repository I thought it would just be a relative link. When using Visual Studio Code on my computer (OSX) I can use relative paths and the images render correctly using the image tag as so:

```
![Alt text](doc/images/readmeFileComparison.png?raw=true "Readme file side by side comparison")
```

Does the image tag have to be different in order for me to view images when viewing the README file with the browser at (example url):

https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/ProjectName/_git/repositoryName?path=%2FREADME.md&version=GBmaster&_a=contents

There is [guidance from Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/markdown-guidance#relative-links) but there must be something I am missing. When the markdown is rendered I get a missing image tag. If I open the image in a new tab I get a HTTP 500 Error and the following message:

> More information about this error
>
> The item doc/images/pullNewChangesFromMaster.png?raw=true does not
>   exist at the specified version, or you do not have permission to
>   access it.

I get the same error even if the addresses have or are missing a leading forward slash from the address.

```
 ![Alt text](doc/images/pullNewChangesFromMaster.png?raw=true "About to Pull down the new changes")
```

or

```
 ![Alt text](/doc/images/pullNewChangesFromMaster.png?raw=true "About to Pull down the new changes")
```

Comment: The guidance does not refer to `?raw=true`: did you try without `?raw=true`?

Comment: That is the answer, want to answer the question?

Comment: Great! I have added an answer to illustrate the proper syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [Guidance page from Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/markdown-guidance#relative-links), I do not see `?raw=true` mentioned anywhere.

So it is best to try your relative link without it.

```
![Alt text](doc/images/pullNewChangesFromMaster.png "About to Pull down the new changes")
```

Comment: Simple. Thanks, I shouldn't have missed that. It's great having another set of eyes look at your work for the fresh perspective that brings.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with images in markdown files, it's important to distinguish two types of possible errors: link errors and syntax errors.

## 1- Link Error

When the link is broken, a broken-image and the text you put in `[]` will be displayed in rendered file. Sample:

```
![not found text](link/to/the/image.png "hover text")
```

[image]

## 2- Syntax Error

There are cases when renderer does not accept the syntax. In that case it will display your whole text.

```
![not found text](link/to/the image.png "hover text")
```

the outcome is like this:

[image]

The problem with second example is that it has an space character in its URL. All spaces in address should be replaced with `%20` like this:

```
![not found text](link/to/the%20image.png "hover text")
```